# ComboBox DropDownList and items from picture and text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox in WindowsForms and I draw items manually. Each item is composed from picture and text, so item is 34 px height.

I want to set DropDownStyle of ComboBox to DropDownList to enable user input. But when I select some of the item, it is deformed, because picture and text is visible. And I want to display only text if user select some item.

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {

            e.DrawBackground();

            if (e.Index > -1)
            {

                Piece item = this.Items[e.Index] as Piece;


                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 6, e.Bounds.Top + 6, 22, 22));

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(item.Image, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 7, e.Bounds.Top + 7, 20, 20));

                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Title, e.Font, 
                    new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds.Left + 34, e.Bounds.Top + 10);

            }

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Do you mean DropDownStyle of DropDown?  This is the setting which enables user input.

2) What do you mean by 'deformed' - and where are you seeing this?

---

Edit:  If this OnDrawItem call is to render the top box - e.State has the ComboBoxEdit bit flag set.  Check for this to render differently.

```
if( (e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) != DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit ) 
{
    // Do drawing logic just for the top edit part
}
else
{
    // Draw logic here for rendering in the drop-down
}
```

Comment: 1) I mean set DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
2) http://www.imagebam.com/image/26d4f1121064349 this is ok, I draw items. http://www.imagebam.com/image/58139c121064355 and I see this when I select some of the item

Comment: Your images aren't corrupted, they are clipped.  You are drawing 32pixel high in a control that is only 15-20.  To have different draw logic for this, key off of e.State -- see my updated post.